Azure static web application has a long response time
I have three static web app services on Azure, each hosting a Svelte application. I am facing the same problem across all of these services. After a 10-15 minute pause in using the application, the first request takes between 6 and 12 seconds on average to complete. This delay only happens with the first request, and subsequent requests work well without any delays.
Application Insights shows operations for sk_render.
I am using the standard hosting plan for all services, and I also activated enterprise-grade edge for one application, but this did not change the situation.
screen from insights

Can you share the code what you've tried

provide the log stream of your azure static webapp


The issue is caused by the "cold start" problem. This is common in serverless or auto-scaling environments like Azure Static Web Apps.
When the application is idle for a certain period, the infrastructure may scale down to save resources.
The first request after this idle period triggers the infrastructure to "wake up."
This "wake-up" process can cause a delay in response time.


Is there an option to prevent a "cold start" for a static web app, similar to the "Always On" option available in regular web services?

Azure Static Web Apps does not have a built-in "Always On" feature similar to what is available in regular web services.
Implement a keep-alive mechanism that sends periodic requests to your application to prevent it from going idle using Azure Logic App, or Azure Function or use third party services like UptimeRobot or Pingdom.

Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

@phantom I have exactly the same problem and tried avoiding this behavior by creating a Azure Logic App that generates a request every 3 minutes. But still the app is hibernated after 5 to 15 minutes so the subsequent call is nearly 20 seconds. Any other idea that may help?

@Yauhen, if you have a static website (i.e. use adapter-static), then you should check out Static website hosting in Azure Storage. Your website will be served faster, and it will be cheaper for you too.

@kwrl It looks like phantom was used to create the answer in ChatGPT, and it does not provide practical advice.

@PeppeL-G Thanks, I will explore this option

I solved the problem by creating an Azure Logic App (as proposed by @phantom) that calls every 1 minute an endpoint.
Every 3 minutes (default value for Recurrence) is not enough! Even then my app was hibernated from every 5 tot 15 minutes, but with 1 minute it seems to work!
